# mysql 2 mssql query translation / list parent's node children

Tags: mysql

Below is a inner of a mssql function - the function the returns the node given and all of its children nodes - which I need to translate into mysql - i tried a mysql view but i get some weird errors in heidisql can any perhaps help to translate it?

```
WITH ListOfNodes AS 
(
  SELECT * FROM Location WHERE LocationID=80
  UNION ALL
  SELECT Location.* FROM Location 
     JOIN ListOfNodes ON Location.LocationID_parent = ListOfNodes.LocationID
)
SELECT * FROM ListOfNodes
```

thanks

Comment: Recursive CTE in MySQL - that makes it way more complex - maybe this will help: https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/7161/10827

Comment: what about this - location and channel table has the same structure - returns the parent info and all the nodes:

"SELECT @ channelid:=channelid AS channelid, channelname, channelid_parent FROM channel WHERE channelid=10
UNION ALL
SELECT @ channelid:=channelid AS channelid, channelname, channelid_parent FROM channel JOIN (SELECT @ channelid:=10) tmp where channelid_parent=@ channelid"

Comment: lose the space between @ and var name eg. @[space]channelid